# Date output incorrect

Tags: swift

Within my swift app I have an iso8601 date (2017-10-27T10:15:23Z) that I receive. I use the following for the DateFormatter dateFormat

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

I then am taking it and using another format to get just the hour/min.

```
h:mm a
```

The code is this

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let nsDate = formatter.date(from: date)
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
print(formatter.string(from: nsDate!))
```

The date outputs

5:15 not 10:15 like I expect it to be.  I've tried using a different final formats but the results are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with an actual value for `date` since `2017-10-27T10:15:23` is not a value that would be successfully parsed with the code you posted.

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: You are parsing a string in the UTC timezone and your final result is in local time. So the results you see are correct for someone living 5 hours west of UTC (such as the Central timezone).

Comment: @rmaddy Wow. Totally forgot about local time from UTC. Thanks for the tip. Now I know what I need to adjust.

Answer (score 1):

> 5:15 not 10:15 like I expect it to be.

If I try it I get 4:15. Which points to the problem-- time zones. I'm six hours from UTC, and you are apparently five hours from UTC.

`DateFormatter` uses your local time zone unless you tell it to use something else. Since your original date string is UTC, you need to tell your date formatter to use UTC:

```
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
```

Then you'll get "10:15".

Comment: This is not true. This won't make a difference when parsing the date. The formatter uses the dateFormat Z to interprete the timezone from the dateString. Setting the timezone to `TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")` will only affect the `string(from: Date)` output string that will be always displayed with UTC time.

Comment: And yet when I add that line, it **does** make a difference, exactly the difference I describe in the answer.

Comment: The date string including the Z means that the date it is UTC time. The dateFormat Z is used to interprete the timezone from the string. So setting the timezone it is not necessary unless you want the string from it to always be displayed at UTC time. I won't explain it again

Comment: Fine. I'll take "I tried it and it works" over "someone said it doesn't work".

Comment: @LeoDabus and Tom. You are both right. Tom - Leo's first comment is correct (just ignore the opening sentence of "This is not true"). He correctly states that setting the timezone here will ultimately only affect the output of `string(from:)` and not when parsing the string (since the date string and the first format specify a timezone) using `date(from:)`. So this answer does give the correct result assuming the OP want's the final result to be in UTC time.

Answer (score -1):

So if I understand the question correctly you are trying to convert time to 24 hours, right? 
Try changing

```
formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
```

to:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm "
```

Comment: No, they are not trying to convert time to 24 hours.